# Visualising the skeleton from openni_tracker in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, openi-tracker, pi-tracker

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to display the skeleton that the openni_tracker detects in rviz. I just installed pi_tracker and ran the skeleton_tracker node that uses it's own program for visualisation, but I know you can track the skeleton in rviz.

The TF display in rviz should be ok, it reports that it successfully found all the /tf-s used for different body parts, but now I don't know how to represent them and visualise them with markers, but I can't find any published topics with the message type that the Marker needs.

First thing I'd like to ask is: do I need another node or something that could publish the topics readable by the Marker?
Second: Do I need to use a Marker display type or something else, like MarkerArray instead?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29341/visualising-the-skeleton-from-openni_tracker-in-rviz/) by [kameleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1934/kameleon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 68 on 2012-03-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kameleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1934/kameleon/) on 2012-03-14**:
Now I tried again, and this time I can't even get the tf's to work. When I  rosrun openni_tracker, it works, but in rviz, there are no fixed frames available. When I roslaunch openni_camera.launch, I can find the /openni_camera frame, but the TF display can't find the tracker's body parts transforms

**Comment by [kameleon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1934/kameleon/) on 2012-03-14**:
I don't remember what exactly I did last time that got it working. I bet that when it worked if I had zoomed out as Pi robot says, I would definitely be able to see the /tf's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can visualize tf by setting the Fixed frame to /openni_camera or something like /head in Rviz! it shows every part of tracked human with a tf related to that part!

---

Originally posted by [Alireza](https://answers.ros.org/users/1637/alireza/) with karma: 717 on 2012-03-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Pi Robot](https://answers.ros.org/users/30/pi-robot/) on 2012-03-08**:
@kameleon If you still don't see the TF frames after following @Alireza's suggestion, make sure you zoom way out in RViz using your mouse wheel--I once found that the frames were just out of the default view.